# Fix skew height and try to prevent stretching

Tags: css, transform

I have a 3 columns parent div, each containing 9 horizontal divs each with a fixed height.
With a bit of trigonometry this is my final result and I'm quite pleased with it.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [colosio.com](http://www.colosio.com/final.png))</sub>

The left divs are moved with transform translate, the right divs are translated(and overlapped) in order to get closer to each other and the middle divs are transformed with the skewY function.
The colors are 1px background images repeated.

Now the problem is my boss isn't happy with the "stretching" the divs in my middle column have when the rotation angle gets wider.

I tried with the transform rotation but didn't like the divs overlapping...

Is there an easy or simple enough approach to solve my problem?
Cheers

EDIT: demo link - http://www.intotheweb.org/cavi/

Comment: Can you post your code (or) create a demo?

Comment: Hi Harry, I added a demo code link at the end of my post

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *wider rotation angle* as I can see only `skewY` but still I don't think you can do much about the stretching. I'd suggest you to have a look at SVG or Canvas for creating things like these. As you have already shown, it is not impossible to create with CSS but just very tough to maintain.

Comment: yes, sorry. I meant wider skewY angle.

Comment: Also I really didn't want to get into Svg or Canvas because I would have to learn them from scratch and didn't want to completely rewrite my code. Is there a faster approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### FOR THE LOVE OF ALL CUTE THINGS, USE SVG!

[SVG documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG)

[Polyline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polyline)

```html
<svg width="600px" viewBox="-2 -2 220 100">
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="0 0, 20 0, 50 32, 70 32, 170 32, 200 0, 220 0" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="2" points="0 10, 20 10, 50 34, 70 34, 170 34, 200 10, 220 10" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="0 20, 20 20, 50 36, 70 36, 170 36, 200 20, 220 20" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="2" points="0 30, 20 30, 50 38, 70 38, 170 38, 200 30, 220 30" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" points="0 40, 20 40, 50 40, 70 40, 170 40, 200 40, 220 40" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="0 50, 20 50, 50 42, 70 42, 170 42, 200 50, 220 50" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="2" points="0 60, 20 60, 50 44, 70 44, 170 44, 200 60, 220 60" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="0 70, 20 70, 50 46, 70 46, 170 46, 200 70, 220 70" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="2" points="0 80, 20 80, 50 48, 70 48, 170 48, 200 80, 220 80" />
  <g class="main">
    <rect x="60" y="30" width="100" height="20" fill="black" stroke="none" />
    <text fill="white" stroke="none" x="72" y="44">SVG Image</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Persjin, sadly I need to keep the outer divs because I'm doing some heavy javascript with them. However I could use this for the diagonal and inner lines. Is there a way to apply a repeated img as background for a polyline?

Comment: @user586883 i think there is, but you can use javascript with svg. Css really is not the tool for this kind of thing.